# Windows 7 Logon Programmatically

Tags: c++, windows-7, autologin, winlogon, proximitysensor

I am doing a R&D of my project. My project is about detecting a human using proximity sensor and return true or false to my system. If true my windows machine should logon automatically. If false no action should occur.

I can able to get true or false status based on user verification. But now i just want to logon Windows 7 machine automatically..,

I just want to know the procedure of how to do Windows 7 logon programmatically..

Any services can be written to achieve this..? or any suggestion how to proceed this..?

Answer (score 3):

Pre-Vista you would use GINA. See [Customizing GINA, Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx) and [Customizing GINA, Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163786.aspx). Post-Vista (therefore including Windows 7) you must use custom credential providers, see [Create Custom Login Experiences With Credential Providers For Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx).

Comment: Does the link you provided is applicable for windows 7?

Comment: Please actually read the answer: "Post-Vista (therefore including Windows 7)"

Comment: The article deals with pure Windows Vista.

Comment: @ShafiqAbbas: So? These things aren't rewritten in _every_ version of Windows. It's rewritten for Vista because of the introduction of UAC.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks much. But these things deals with smart card reader. I want automatically loggin module alone based on true or false status.

Comment: This *is* how you login an user. The smartcard is just an example.