# Run C# application on the logon menu

Tags: c#, c++, windows

I have an Arduino board plugged into the PC. I need to send certain characters from the Arduino board to the PC.

The application will be running on the logon page, whenever it receives a special character it will login a specific user account.

I'll do my research on the other parts, but my main important part it to launch that app or service before the user login in Windows.

Is this possible? Am I able to achieve this in .net? If it's not achievable, what ways and techniques can be used to make it work?

Any info, examples and links will be great!

Thanks.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582859/windows-7-logon-programatically

Comment: A service will start before the logon page. I dont see the problem.

Comment: @leppie: you can't login using a service

Comment: what about WindowsImpersonationContext ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easy way: Write an app (a console app for instance) and in Windows Scheduler define a task which runs "at system start-up" (with whatever user you need).

The not easy way (but more options if you need some): Write a Windows Service and set it's start type to automatic.

Comment: and how will you login a specific user account?

Comment: If you use Windows Scheduler you just enter the username and password when you are defining the task; if you write a Windows Service you can use impersonation. And it's possible that I am not understanding what you described here (or it's possible too that you should provide a more specific description).

Comment: What about `WindowsImpersonationContext` ?

Comment: @n0idea The question is "how to start an app at start up, before user logging in?". One does not necessarily have to impersonate the user and can run the app under local system user. What about `WindowsImpersonationContext`?

Comment: Please help make this better by explaining the down-vote.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows XP, the login process could be automated using [GINA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You had to create a MSGINA.DLL that was able to interact with the Winlogon process.

For Windows Vista and later, GINA was dropped and you now have to create a [Credential Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx)